# descendant match not caught though given in template

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML

```
<list>
     <list.item><label>3.7.8</label>    <emphasis type="italic">Health Impact</emphasis></list.item>
    <list.item><label>3.7.8.1</label>   A health </list.item>
    <list.item><label><star.page>216</star.page> 3.7.8.2</label>    The health risk assessment shall include the following key steps:
      <list>
        <list.item><label>(i)</label>   a systematic identification</list.item>
        <list.item><label>(ii)</label>  an assessment</list.item>
        <list.item><label>(iii)</label> an </list.item>
        <list.item><label>(iv)</label>  recommendation </list.item>
     </list>
    </list.item>
    <list.item><label>3.7.8.3</label>   The health </list.item>
    <list.item><label>3.7.8.4</label>   The environmental health sources.</list.item>
    <list.item><label>3.7.8.5</label>   It is also necessary e Project. (emphasis supplied)</list.item>
</list>
```

and the below XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
</body>
</html>

    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root">
<xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="list">
<xsl:variable name="strl">
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::list.item/label/string-length(./text())"/>
</xsl:variable>
<!--<xsl:value-of select="$strl"/>-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($strl) > '7'">
            <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist1">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="orderitem" match="list.item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./label/node()[1][self::star.page]" mode="first"/>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:if test="./label">
                    <span class="item-num">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./label/text()"/>
                    </span>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./text()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label)]"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </div>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here I've mentioned `<xsl:value-of select="descendant::list.item/label/string-length(./text())"/>` and in condition i gave if its value is more than seven chars, it should take `orderedlist` else should take `orderedlist1`.

Here the condition is in the current list, if there are any `label` whose length is greater than 7(any label in current list), it should take `orderedlist1`, else `orderedlist`.
 please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate your description "in the current list, if there are any label whose length is greater than 7" into `<xsl:if test="descendant::list.item/label[string-length() gt 7]">...</xsl:if>`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the quick response, this is working fine, but when there is a case like `<list.item><label><star.page>94</star.page> (a)</label>`, `orderedlist1` is caught instead of `orderedlist`

Comment: Well your English description "label whose length is greater" would include an text inside the label, including that of other child or descendant elements, so that is why I have taken `label[string-length() gt 7]`. If you don't want that then we need a better description of which length you want, perhaps `descendant::list.item/label[string-length(string-join(text(), '')) gt 7]` which would concatenate all text node children and then compute the length is more what you want.

Comment: Does this exclude any other child nodes. i.. only text is considered?

Comment: Yes, `text()` is short for `child::text()` and selects all child text nodes, and the `string-join` concatenates the values.

Comment: i want to ignore the child(`star.text`) :-(

Comment: That is an element node, so it is not selected by doing `child::text()` respectively `text()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65592/discussion-between-user3872094-and-martin-honnen).

Comment: I'm unsing this `max(descendant::list.item/label[string-length(string-join(text(), '')) gt 7])` to find the maximum stringlength
but it gives me this error `FORG0001: cannot convert xs:untypedAtomic with value 94 (a) to xs:double`